# HTML Form Input to Python

Tags: python, html, input, textbox, html-input

So In my HTML code I have this

```html
 <form>  Curtain Opening Time: <br>  
    <input type ="text" name="Curtain_OPENTIME">
    <br> 
</form>
```

This creates a simple text box with text next to it saying "Curtain Opening Time: " (some of It I do not understand).
The objective of this is to input a time e.g. 8:00 AM, the user then presses enter to 'register'/enter the time and I can then use that variable entered in the HTML Web Page to do some things in my Python Code in my Raspberry Pi 3. Please help, thank you! :)

Comment: You can use the flask library for this

Comment: This question is very broad, just some tips: You'll need to set up a webserver on your Raspberry Pi. There are many options, for example: https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/python-web-server-with-flask/

Comment: Yes, and then you can make it a real website with ngrok (localhost tunneling)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def student():
    return render_template('yourfile.html')

@app.route('/result',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def result():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form['Curtain_OPENTIME']
        print(result)
        return "thank you for filling out this form"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

Here is the python code to get the result. Use it with your HTML in the same folder named yourfile.html. Then run it and go to the localhost it is running on.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I have the server running on the Raspberry pi, I had just not mentioned it to keep detail to a minimum for simplicity purposes. I have put your request method and result code in thank you very much and I get it saying "GET /?Curtain_OPENTIME=6 HTTP/1.1" 200. And it doesn't print out the variable; the time/number I put in. Thank you for your help

Comment: Oh, and make a folder called templates and put yourfile.html inside it

Comment: Yes I have done that I have the python file and then in a templates file I have the .html file called index.html

Comment: It's just how am I able to know that the variable in python called 'result' contains the value I entered in the web page. Because in Raspberry Pi using print and return tends to not output the value of the variable. So basically, What can I do to know the value of the variable 'result'? Thank you

Comment: Well, you said "some things in my Python Code in my Raspberry Pi 3"

Comment: Yes but it doesn't print out the variable.

Comment: You could do something at that time, like sound an alarm or buzzer (using the gpio pins)